# Inserting a predefined value into mysql if the form's text input field remains blank

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

The following form collects data about the color preference of the visitors.

how can I insert a default value (For example, `"No Color Chosen"` is default value here which isn't available in database) into mysql database using explode function if the users submit the blank form when I don't want to prevent users from submitting the blank form.

Although I'm not sure if use of explode function is the right way to do it I attempt to do with the following syntax

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {    
$color = "No Color Chosen ({$_POST['color_name']};)";
$colors = explode (" ", $color);

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO colortable (color_name) VALUES (%s)",


GetSQLValueString(trim($colors[]), "text")),

  mysql_select_db($database_x, $x;
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $x) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "choice.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
```

---

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1"   id="form1">
    <table align="center">
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td align="right" nowrap="nowrap">Enter Color Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="color_name" value="" size="32" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="baseline">
            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Color Name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How should I define the following value

```
  value=
    "<?php echo $_POST($colors[0]);?>"
    "<?php echo $_POST($colors[1]);?>"
```

as conditional statement of form's text input value

```
<input type="text" name="color_name" value="conditional statement goes here" size="32" />
```

in this case so that the default value default value "No Color Chosen" that derives from  `<?php echo $_POST($colors[0]);?>` is inserted on blank form submission ?

by the way, here the other element of the $color array `$colors[1]` shall post the user input to the database through the value `"<?php echo $_POST($colors[1]);?>"` if there is any.

is there any other easy way to do it?

Comment: If you can avoid it, please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand how your form even works.. how ever the best idea which I can give you is to set the value as this (somewhere at the beginning)....

```
    $color = "DEFAULT VALUE";
    if(isset($_POST['color_name']) && !empty($_POST['color_name'])){
       $color = $_POST['color_name'];
    }
```

And after that line use the $color variable for next actions ..

Comment: If you want you can set and at the if 
&& !empty($_POST['color_name'])
To check if the value is not empty.

Comment: `value="<?php echo "$color";?>"` doesn't input anything into database on submission of form if the form's input field remains bank. i don't want to prevent users from submitting the blank form. thanks,

Comment: My code is for when you work with already submited form data.
When users submit form if isset color_name it will overwrite the default value else it will stay Defatult..

Comment: thumb up ! the syntax not only work with already submitted form data available in database but also insert fresh predefined default values into database if the respective form fields remain blank during submission. thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer the PHP question directly, but at least the placeholder text functionality can be accomplished by default in HTML5 without any need for Javascript or testing that the default value isn't being entered into the database:

`<input type="text" placeholder="my text to be replaced"/>`

Support looks to be pretty good (http://wufoo.com/html5/) though you can easily polyfill this in browsers that don't support it - see here: https://github.com/ginader/HTML5-placeholder-polyfill

An example in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/jjnbF/1/

Comment: it's good as form's input hint. this isn't what actually i've asked for. thanks,